# CORS headers not working for File Upload from Angular to PHP

Tags: php, angular, typescript, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to upload images from my Angular 8+ frontend to my php backend and sending text data works without a problem, but wanting to send image files to a folder in my wamp directory, no cigar unfortunately...

It worked earlier, but this morning it decided it did not want to work anymore. I tried adding to the CORS headers, but nothing seems wrong there.

html:

```
<input type="button" value="Test" (click)='Advertise($event.target.files)'>
```

component:

```
ToUpload()
  {
    let images = this.carImages.nativeElement;
    let j=10;
    for(let i of images.files)
    { 
      console.log(i);
      if(i.type=='image/jpeg')
      {
        let frmData = new FormData();
        frmData.append('file',i,(j+'.jpg').toString());
        this.uploadService.UploadImages(frmData).subscribe(val=>
        {
        })
      }
      if(i.type=='image/png')
      {
        let frmData = new FormData();
        frmData.append('file',i,(j+'.png').toString());
        this.uploadService.UploadImages(frmData).subscribe(val=>
        {
        })
      }
      j++;
    }

  }
  Advertise(files:FileList)
  {
    this.ToUpload();
  }
```

service:

```
UploadImages(image:FormData):Observable<any>
  {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiURL+"/api/BLL/imageUpload.php?action=upload",image) as Observable<any>;
  }
```

CORS_Headers.php

```
<?php
// Default Header
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization,Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("MIME-Version: 1.0");
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8");
// Response type header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

imageUpload.php

```
<?php
require_once '../BLL/CORS_Headers.php';

//require '../DAL/DBHandler.php';

//use DAL\DBHandler;

$action=$_GET['action'];
if($action=='upload')
{
    $tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    // Get File Name
    $actualName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    // New path
    $actualPath = '../Images/' . $actualName;
    //$tempPath = compressImage($tempPath,$actualPath,60);
    // Move File into new path
    move_uploaded_file($tempPath, $actualPath)
    // Get real path of moved file here
    $realPath = realpath(__DIR__ . '/' . $actualPath);
    // Delete the file
    echo "Uploaded";
}
```

Expected result: Just do the upload

Actual result: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/BLL/imageUpload.php?action=upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

and

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/BLL/imageUpload.php?action=upload", ok: false, …}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

Add below Code in .htaccess file PHP(Server) side

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
</IfModule>
```

Angular Code

page.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" />
```

npm install

```
"rxjs": "~6.5.1", //npm i rxjs@6.5.1 --save
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2" // npm i rxjs-compat@6.5.2 --save
```

page.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';

fileUpload(event){
      let formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);

      this.ImageUpload(formData).subscribe(val => {
        //enter custom code
      })
}


ImageUpload(formData):Observable<any>{
    var token = localStorage.getItem('keyToken');
    const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': token });
    return this.http
    .post(URL, formData,{headers:myHeaders})
    .concatMap(data=>{
      return Observable.of(data);
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: how did you get that concatMap() from rxJs going?

Comment: what angular version did you use?